# C# MongoDB Find and Update Many

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm looking for a way to atomically retrieve a list of 100 documents at a time and mark them as fetched.
The overall idea is to save some network traffic and have a speedy process.

Basically a Find**Many**AndUpdateAsync equivalent to `_collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);` is what I am looking for.

What other options are there?

Comment: no such method exists in the c# driver let alone in mongo server. I guess the best you could do is to first retrieve your 100 docs and then in a second update query set the filter to match all 100 IDs with an $in operator. for atomicity wrap the whole thing in a transaction.